# Folder Redirection using Windows 7 Client and Windows Server 2003 DC

Tags: folder-redirection

Situation

Trying to introduce Windows 7 Clients into my Server 2003 environment.  Having problems with Folder Redirection via GPO.

I created a Test OU which contains Two Computer accounts.  One Windows 7 and One Windows XP.  It also contains Two User Accounts.  One Domain Admin account and one Basic User account.

On my Windows 7 Client I created a GPO and Linked it to my Test OU.

```
User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Folder Redirection > Documents

Setting: Basic (Redirect everyone's folder to the same location)

Path: %HomeShare%%HomePath%

Grant User exclusive rights to Documents = Disabled

Move the contents of Documents to the new location = Enabled

Also apply redirection policy to Windows 2000, XP, etc = Enabled

Policy Removal Behavior = Leave Contents

Music, Pictures, and Videos = Follow the Documents folder

User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Offline Files

Synchronize all offline files before logging off = Disabled

Synchronize all offline files when logging on = Disabled

User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer

Turn off Windows Libraries features that rely on indexed file data = Enabled
```

Folder redirection works perfectly fine on my Windows XP computer when logged in as the domain admin or basic user accounts.

Folder redirection does not work on Windows 7 with either user account.  WHY???

gpresult /z > C:\Info.txt reads the following...

```
USER SETTINGS

CN=Test User,OU= Test,DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=prv
Last time Group Policy was applied: 9/24/2010 at 10:57:24 AM
Group Policy was applied from:      DC.DOMAINNAME.prv
Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
Domain Name:                        DOMAINNAME
Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Default Domain Policy
    Folder Redirection
    Local Group Policy

The user is a part of the following security groups
---------------------------------------------------
    Domain Users
    Everyone
    BUILTIN\Users
    NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
    CONSOLE LOGON
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    This Organization
    LOCAL
    CERTSVC_DCOM_ACCESS
    Medium Mandatory Level

The user has the following security privileges
----------------------------------------------


Resultant Set Of Policies for User
-----------------------------------

    Software Installations
    ----------------------
        N/A

    Logon Scripts
    -------------
        N/A

    Logoff Scripts
    --------------
        N/A

    Public Key Policies
    -------------------
        N/A

    Administrative Templates
    ------------------------

        GPO: Folder Redirection
            KeyName:     Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\DisableIndexedLibraryExperience
            Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

    Folder Redirection
    ------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Browser User Interface
    ----------------------------------------
        GPO: Default Domain Policy
            Large Animated Bitmap Name:      N/A
            Large Custom Logo Bitmap Name:   N/A
            Title BarText:                   N/A
            UserAgent Text:                  N/A
            Delete existing toolbar buttons: No

    Internet Explorer Connection
    ----------------------------
        HTTP Proxy Server:   N/A
        Secure Proxy Server: N/A
        FTP Proxy Server:    N/A
        Gopher Proxy Server: N/A
        Socks Proxy Server:  N/A
        Auto Config Enable:  No
        Enable Proxy:        No
        Use same Proxy:      No

    Internet Explorer URLs
    ----------------------
        GPO: Default Domain Policy
            Home page URL:           http://sharepoint/Pages/HomePage.aspx
            Search page URL:         N/A
            Online support page URL: N/A

    Internet Explorer Security
    --------------------------
        Always Viewable Sites:     N/A
        Password Override Enabled: False

        GPO: Default Domain Policy
            Import the current Content Ratings Settings:      No
            Import the current Security Zones Settings:       Yes
            Import current Authenticode Security Information: No
            Enable trusted publisher lockdown:                No

    Internet Explorer Programs
    --------------------------
        GPO: Default Domain Policy
            Import the current Program Settings: No
```

Any Ideas??????

Comment: What server OS is on your DC's? And What level to you have your AD set to? i.e. if you are on Windows Server 2008 R2 for your DC's (rec min), but your domain is still 2003, you may experience "buggy" results with users on redirect. Just my 2 cents, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to thank all who posted.  I used all the tools you've mentioned to narrow down the problem.

> It seems like the GPO I posted was the
>   correct configuration after all. All I
>   did was  change the order of my GPO's.
>   I moved the Folder Redirection GPO to
>   the top and the Default Domain Policy
>   GPO to the bottom.

I guess there is something in the Default Domain Policy GPO that does not agree with my Folder Redirection GPO.

I am a new user to Server Fault.... and I am a believer.  Thanks you guys!!!

Comment: Now's a good time to run GPRESULTS, it will show you what GPO's were applied and\or denied and will show you the settings that were applied by which GPO (the winning GPO). Since you've narrowed it down to GPO processing order, I might suggest putting things back the way they were, running GPRESULTS and looking at the settings being applied to determine what setting in the Default Domain policy are conflicting\over-riding your Folder Redirection GPO.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning on Folder Redirection logging and then check the log file for clues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759194(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Run rsop.msc on the Windows 7 client. It should tell you the reason why it's not redirecting.

Comment: The Event Log is more likely to give you good hard information about why the policy isn't actually being applied than RSoP will. RSoP is nice to show you what policies are actually supposed to apply, but if you find that the policy is supposed to apply but isn't then RSoP doesn't help much. In general, the Folder Redirection Client-Side Extension *wants* to tell you what's wrong via the Event Log.

Comment: @Evan - I'm going to only partially agree with you. The event log will likely show stuff as well, but rsop is not good for just showing you what's supposed to be applied. If there is an error applying a policy, it will give you information about the error as well.

Comment: RSOP and GPRESULTS may both show errors applying a policy but they won't show you what errors were encountered applying a setting in a policy (that I've ever seen or am aware of). If the Folder Redirection policy isn't being applied due to a permissions or path problem, that's not going to show up in RSOP or GPRESULTS.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test at the moment but if I recall correctly, the GP templates changed for Vista/Win 7 because the special folder names (Documents, Music, etc) & paths changed.  These mgmt templates aren't included in Server 2003.  I can't find the MS documentation for this but a quick search shows it discussed [here](http://n3ilb.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/vista-group-policy-in-a-server-2003-active-directory/).

2 options that will let you see the correct redirect options for Vista/Win7:

1. Install Server 2008 istance into the domain, add as a DC (but you can leave AD at the 2003 level) and manage GP from this server.
2. Install Remote Server Administration Tools on a Vista/Win 7 machine and manage GP using RSAT.

[Download 32 bit RSAT here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=9FF6E897-23CE-4A36-B7FC-D52065DE9960&amp;amp;displaylang=en&displaylang=en).

[Download 64 bit RSAT here.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=D647A60B-63FD-4AC5-9243-BD3C497D2BC5&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

to answer this thread as none of the answers have solved this issue...

Win7 users folders and WinXP are in different path...
you can manually adjust the path

or create the GPO using the win7 RSAT tool and use the folder redirection policy within the GPO editing window

good luck